Role of ethanol in ethanol - CaCl2 bath used for crosslinking film
In an experiment a dry film of sodium-alginate (polysaccharide) is immersed in a 70% v/v aqueous solution containing 5 % w/v CaCl2. The result is that the Ca2+ crosslinks the polysaccharides.
Regarding the role of ethanol, I assume that it won't dissolve the alginate film like water would do that's why they used it.  Is this the reason and/or there any other purpose for using it?

If there is moisture left in the alginate film, 70% ethanol should dry it somewhat. It might be interesting to try the experiment while varying the alcohol/water ratio.
